# Retrieve Wikipedia search for a remote user

Tags: php, wikipedia

I would like to be able to retrieve the search made by a user from his browser on the wikipedia.org page.

**I know it exists because a magic app (available from Apple Store) does it.**

How to do that ?

**Here is what I know about the application:**

1. The user goes to the website of the application's publisher. Then
   clicks on a link that triggers a PHP script.
2. At the end of the PHP  script, the Internet user is redirected to
   the wikipedia.org page.
3. At this moment any search made by the Internet user will be sent to
   the  website of the publisher of the application (and therefore
   visible    later on the application itself)

Here is a small diagram to illustrate my point:
[explanation diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQIzk.png)

How to do ? Should we call a Wikipedia API by indicating the HTTP_REFERER?

Thanks for your help

Comment: [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions) allow you to do all kinds of things with others' sites (such as capturing keyboard input on the Wikipedia search form). Do mind user privacy & consent while working on something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you ask StackOverflow community how to hijack Wikipedia's requests? To the best of my knowledge, Wikipedia does not offer an official way to do this. You can, however, use Wikipedia's API to submit search queries on the user's behalf, see https://mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search. But, please do not use what your original diagram proposed - it could easily qualify as an attack.